# List of Enum allowable values in Swagger

Tags: java, enums, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have an enum which has around 60 values but in the swagger, I want to show only some of the values. I'm using swagger v3.

Taking dummy example:

**Enum**

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;

@Schema(name = "Fruit", description = "List of all possible Fruits")
enum Fruit {
    APPLE,
    BANANA,
    GUAVA,
    KIWI,
    ...
}
```

**Class that uses Enum**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Builder
@JsonIgnoreProperties
@Schema(name = "Bucket")
class Bucket {
    @Schema(description = "Selected fruits") List<Fruit> fruits;
}
```

**Swagger file**: Showing all the fruit values. Here, I want to show only `APPLE` and `BANANA` fruits value.

```
            fruits:
                type: "array"
                items:
                    type: "string"
                    enum:
                        - "APPLE"
                        - "BANANA"
                        - "GUAVA"
                        - "KIWI"
                        - ...
```

**Tried code 1**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Builder
@JsonIgnoreProperties
@Schema(name = "Bucket")
class Bucket {
    @ApiModelProperty(allowableValues = "APPLE, BANANA")
    @Schema(description = "Selected fruits")
    List<Fruit> fruits;
}
```

**Tried code 2**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Builder
@JsonIgnoreProperties
@Schema(name = "Bucket")
class Bucket {
    @Schema(description = "Selected fruits", type = "[Ljava.util.String;", allowableValues = {"APPLE", "BANANA"})
    List<Fruit> fruits;
}
```

**Output for code 1 & 2**: It's still showing all the values

```
            fruits:
                type: "array"
                items:
                    type: "string"
                    enum:
                        - "APPLE"
                        - "BANANA"
                        - "GUAVA"
                        - "KIWI"
                        - ...
```

Comment: You'll have to define another enum with just the APPLE and BANANA values.

Comment: Actually, the 'Fruit' enum is used by many DTOs/APIs. Right now, all allowable values ​​from various APIs have been added to the 'Fruit' enum only. So, for an API, I want to show only their allowable values.

I know the best solution is to define enums for each API, but creating multiple enums would take a lot of effort right now.

So, I need some way, where I can define all allowable values ​​at DTO level.